# crystal report display count of records

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have crystal generating the following output in my Details section

```
Cats    Group   
Number  How Old 
________________________ 
12      0-30 days old  
32      0-30 days old  
34      31-60 days old  

Dogs    Group      
Number  How Old  
________________________
22      over 61 days old  
123     0-30 days old
```

but i need the above info in a table format

```
Group  0-30 days old  31-60 days old  over 61 days old  
______________________________________________________
Cats   2               1                 0  
Dogs   1               0                 1
```

thanks

Comment: have u tried using "Cross Tab" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Cross-Tab;

Open Cross-tab expert

Drag `group` into `columns`
Drag `animal type` into `rows`
Drag `animal`into `value` and set `count` as summarize option